# jQuery returning wrong height value for image in some environments

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have an image slider with the left half of the div showing an image and the right half showing a caption with grey background. Since I'm using Bootstrap for UI, the image changes dimensions as the widow changes, so I'm using jQuery to keep the caption sized correctly.  This works fine on localhost but not on my staging environment.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //resizes carousel right side as window changes
 function size_carousel(){
    var height = $('.carousel-inner .item img:visible').height();
    console.log($('.carousel-inner .item img:visible').height());
    $('.carousel-caption').each(function(){
        $(this).height(height);
    });
 }
 $(window).resize(function() {
    size_carousel();
 });
 $('#myCarousel').ready(function(){
    size_carousel();
 });
});
```

HTML excerpt:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                 <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                 <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                 <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/test/demo1.jpeg" class="span6"/>
                <div class="carousel-caption span6">
                        <h3 class="cat">Tech News</h3>
                        <h2 class="title">Article Title</h2>
                        <p class="dek well well-small">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.  Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div> <!-- /caption -->
          </div><!-- /item -->
    </div>
```

On refresh, in `localhost` the console shows the correct value (depending on window size, it varies b/w 2-300) while the staging environment always returns `30` regardless of window size. When you resize the window, it returns the correct value and the caption adjusts correctly so the only problem is in the initial page load.

`localhost` is MAMP and staging is a MediaTemple gs server, both with the same WordPress install and jQuery versions so I'm having a hard time isolating what could cause it to behave differently.

You can see it [in action here](http://paymentjournal.com/).

Comment: the link you have, is this working or not working? I checked the link in firefox the height of the caption is resizing properly but since the content is more than the height it just gets hidden. You could put overflow scroll on the caption div and you will see a scroll bar to see the rest of the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    size_carousel();
 });
 $('#myCarousel').ready(function(){  //ready event is only for document!
    size_carousel();
 });
```

To that:

```
$(window).on('resize load',function() {
    size_carousel();
 });
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly!  Thanks!